# Multiple libgcc_s libraries when linking on Solaris with studio 12.5

Tags: linker, solaris-studio

I'm trying to move to Developer Studio 12.5 and enable the C++11 options. My software links openssl using the Oracle provided library in /usr/sfw. This appears to depend on an older libgcc_s.so than the one now used for the C++ 11 STL. So I get the following:

```
CC -o binary -B direct -z origin -std=c++11 object_files.o -Lblah/lib -R\$ORIGIN/../lib -lotherlib -L/usr/sfw/lib -R/usr/sfw/lib -lcrypto -lsocket
unused $ADDVERS specification from file '/opt/developerstudio12.5/lib/compilers/CC-gcc/gcc_version.map' for object 'libgcc_s.so'
version(s):
        GCC_4.2.0
```

Is there some way for the two libgcc_s.so instances to coexist in one binary with references from libcrypto going to one and from the STL to the other? Looking at the Oracle linker and libraries document shows some promising options like -B group but that perhaps only works for dlopen.

I realise that I could just recompile openssl (or perhaps libressl) but it would be nicer to use the one from the OS and my colleague reckons that Sun's build makes use of hardware crypto features on the SPARC.

Comment: Did you manage to get rid of the error message?

Comment: No. error message is still a problem.

Comment: Try using the switch -m64 while compiling. CC -m64 -std=c++11 filename.cpp

Comment: Switching the code the build 64-bit isn't an option, unfortunately. Am stuck with 32-bit dependencies.